# MongoDB Prematurely reached end of stream

Tags: java, mongodb

I get a Prematurely reached end of stream error when trying to connect to MongoDB Atlas Free Tier.  Using Java 1.8 and Mongo Driver 3.8.0. Does this have any thing to do with the Cluster setup in Atlas? I got the same program working with my MongoDB localhost.

Any Idea?

Java Test class

```
import org.bson.Document;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientURI;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;

public class MongoTest {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI(
            "mongodb://username:password@cluster0-****.mongodb.net");

    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("account");

    System.out.println("Hello");

    MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("users");

    System.out.println(collection.count());

    mongoClient.close();

  }
}
```

Error:

```
    Jul 15, 2018 12:32:04 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[cluster0-****.mongodb.net:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
Hello
Jul 15, 2018 12:32:04 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Cluster description not yet available. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
Jul 15, 2018 12:32:04 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server cluster0-****.mongodb.net:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:92)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveResponseBuffers(InternalStreamConnection.java:554)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:425)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:289)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:255)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:83)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:33)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:106)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:63)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:127)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=cluster0-****.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.BaseCluster.getDescription(BaseCluster.java:179)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SingleServerCluster.getDescription(SingleServerCluster.java:41)
at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate.getConnectedClusterDescription(MongoClientDelegate.java:136)
at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate.createClientSession(MongoClientDelegate.java:94)
at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.getClientSession(MongoClientDelegate.java:249)
at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:172)
at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.executeCount(MongoCollectionImpl.java:248)
at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.count(MongoCollectionImpl.java:183)
at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.count(MongoCollectionImpl.java:171)
at MongoTest.main(MongoTest.java:21)
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have added your client address (easily found by typing "what is my IP address" into Google) to the IP whitelist for your cluster. Without this, you will not be able to connect.

The IP whitelist is under the security tab.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Joe. But I added it.

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you very much.  you saved my day!

Comment: I had the same problem, but it was related to mongodb version, my application has been tested with mongodb 4.0 but I used mongodb 5.0